# For loop with while statement sticking on certain iterations

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have code which simulates a Markov jump process.

I am trying to increase the number of realisations, Rr whilst reducing the computation time. The code is runs for some values and then will randomly get stuck and I don't know why exactly. I think it may be to do with my while loop, although I am unsure on how to get around this. If anyone could provide some insight that would be great.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import time


t = time.time()
#Initial jump value
n0 = 1
#Constant
cbar = 1
#Constant
L = 1
#Constant
tau = 2*L/cbar


#Empty list to store N series
N_array = []
#Empty list to store z series
z_array = []
#Number of initial realisations
Rr = 2000
for r in range(0,Rr):
    #Set initial z series values to be zero
    z = [0]
    #Set initial jump process values to be n0
    N = [n0]
    #Set iteration to be zero
    j = 0
    #While the value of N[j] series (realisation r) is greater than zero and j is less than jmax
    while N[j] > 0:
        #Form next value in z series according to exponential clock, parameter n^2, since Lloc = 2, cbar = 1, L=1
        #In python the argument of this function is beta = 1/lambda, hence 1/n^2
        z.append(z[j] + np.random.exponential(1/N[j]**2)) 
        #Pick jump at position j+1 to be N[j] -1 or +1 with prob 1/2
        N.append(N[j] + np.random.choice([-1,1]))
        #Update iteration
        j = j+1
    #Store N,z realisation if sum dz < 10 say
    if sum(np.diff(z)) < 10:
        N_array.append(N)
        z_array.append(z)
        print(r/RR*100,'%)


elapsed = time.time() - t
print('Elapsed time =',elapsed,'seconds')
```

Comment: learn how to use the python debugger `pdb` and figure out where exactly and why it's stuck. Generally, appending to a list in an inner loop sounds like a design mistake.

Comment: I may be wrong, but looks like the code that you have posted generates a syntax error:

    print(r/RR*100,'%)
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I've run the code few times, never stuck. It is just sometimes faster, sometimes is slower. 
When working with random in the while loop the run time will vary.
You have:

while N[j] > 0:
        N.append(N[j] + np.random.choice([-1,1]))
        j = j+1

sometimes you will get N[j] < 0 fast, sometimes not so fast.

Comment: It gets slower as the number of realisations increases, I get segmentation core dump faults over 10,000 realisations